# Trying to Center Top Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, bigcommerce

Making adjustments to the following bigcommerce theme: https://cornerstone-light-demo.mybigcommerce.com and I cant seem to get the top nav (nav.navuser) to center align. I've tried various combinations of text-align:center;, and margin:0 auto; to no avail.

Comment: So many mistakes in code. Provide cleaner Jsfiddle code and I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes:

```
.navUser-section.navUser-section--alt {
    /* add the following rule */
    display: inline-block;
}

.navUser-section--alt {
   /* change float:right to float: none */
    float: none;
}

.navUser{
    /* add the following rule */
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Looks like I was trying to use block instead of inline-block, which was causing my issues.